# How can I multiply the price by the correct currency Value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Just started learning VBA

I want to multiply the product price with the currency value to get a new price.

```
No      Name    Quantity Price Product Currency OrderID       Currency  $
1       Tim     5       5       A       HKD     RX12            HKD 1
2       Alan    6       5       A       HKD     PR22            USD 7.8
3       Alan    2       6       B       USD     PR22            CAN 6
4       Bob     3       5       A       HKD     ED45            
5       Bob     8       8       C       CAN     ED45            
6       Tim     10      6       B       USD     AS63            
7       Rose    12      8       C       CAN     LM36            
8       Cathy   15      6       B       USD     JI48            
9       Rose    2       5       A       HKD     HG54            
10      Tim     8       6       B       USD     VB87
```

Here's the code I've tried so far. I keep getting object not defined errors. How can I fix this?

```vb
Sub NP()

    Dim NP, i As Integer
    NP = Range("L2:L11").Value

    For i = 1 To 10
        P = Cells(4, i)
        curr = Cells(6, i)

        If curr = "HKD" Then
            NP = Range("J2").Value * P    
        ElseIf curr = "USD" Then
            NP = Range("J3").Value * P    
        Else
            NP = Range("J4").Value * P
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Clive I rewrote his question, can you take it off of hold so I can answer?

Comment: Note that `Dim NP, i As Integer` only declares `i` as `Integer` but `NP` as `Variant`. In VBA you must specify a type for **every** variable (otherwise it is `Variant` by default): `Dim NP As Double, i As Long` Also [I recommend to use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520) and `Double` for `NP`.

Answer (score 0):

If the data looks like in the sheet below

[image]

You can do that with a simple formula in column L

```
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(F:F,I:I,0))*D:D
```

It uses the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) to find the currency (column F) in the currency list (column I) and return its row number. And combines it with the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) to return the currency factor (column J) of that matched row, to finally multiply it with the price (column D).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your biggest problem was how you were declaring your variables. Also, the `P = 1 + i` helps you to avoid running an infinite loop in the first cell. Hope this helps!

```
Sub NP()

    Dim NP As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim P As Long
    Dim curr As String

    For i = 2 To 10
    P = Cells(i, 4)
    curr = Cells(i, 6)
        If curr = "HKD" Then
            NP = Range("J2").Value * P
        ElseIf curr = "USD" Then
            NP = Range("J3").Value * P
        Else
            NP = Range("J4").Value * P
        End If
    P = 1 + i
    Next i

End Sub
```